# jQuery detect if a radio button is changed by a human or not form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a search function and some filters, which use radio buttons. If the radio button values change (by a human) it will submit the form with jQuery. My problem is, if the page reloads I am setting the radio buttons according to the GET parameters of my URL via javascript. They will still get detected as a human action and my site keeps reloading (looping). I was trying to use the `originalEvent` property.
How can I stop my site from looping? It should not reload the page, on refresh.
It works for some filters for example price, but other radio buttons with the same function cause looping like my genre radio button.

**Radio Change Function / GET Variable Helper / Set Radio Button / Document Ready**

```
    $('input:radio').change(function(e){
        if (e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')) {
            alert("human change");
            $("#filter_form" ).submit();
        }  
        else{

            alert("not human click");
        }
    }
);



function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  console.log('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');



function ready_price_filter(){
    var price_filter_value = getQueryVariable('price_filter');
    if (price_filter_value){
        $('#price_' + price_filter_value).click();
        console.log("setting ");
    }
}


$(function(){        
        ready_price_filter();
});
```

Comment: create a hidden input field from the serverside called "radioGet" and set to value 1 if the radio status was caused by GET? Then you know when its caused by GET atleast :)

Comment: @Pekka smartest answer. I didn't think about that. thx

Comment: If you post this as answer I can accept it.